# Passing a value to a text box in navigation link view

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

I am trying to pass a value from a text box in my first view to a text box in my second view.

```
struct FirstView: View {
@State private var inputTextValue = ""
var body: some View {        
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            TextField("",text: $inputTextValue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .border(.gray)
            NavigationLink(destination: {SecondView(incomingTextFieldvalue: inputTextValue)}, label: {Text("To second view")})
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
var incomingTextFieldvalue: String
@State var textFieldValue = "Initial Value in view 2"
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        TextField("",text: $textFieldValue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            .border(.gray)
        Spacer()
        Text("Incoming value: \(incomingTextFieldvalue)")
        Text("This value: \(textFieldValue)")
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

So, what I want exactly is that the text box in the second view has the passed value filled in initially.

I have tried various solutions, but have not been able to get the solution that I need. Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set incoming value to internal in `onAppear`, like

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    TextField("",text: $textFieldValue)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
        .border(.gray)
    Spacer()
    Text("Incoming value: \(incomingTextFieldvalue)")
    Text("This value: \(textFieldValue)")

    Spacer()
}
.onAppear { textFieldValue = incomingTextFieldvalue }   // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

*(of course if you don't want to share them, which is unclear)

Comment: In my case I don't want to share the data between the views.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@Binding` like so:

In FirstView:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var inputTextValue = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                TextField("",text: $inputTextValue)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .border(.gray)
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(incomingTextFieldvalue: $inputTextValue), label: {Text("To second view")})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In SecondView:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var textFieldValue = "Initial Value in view 2"
    @Binding var incomingTextFieldvalue: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextField("",text: $incomingTextFieldvalue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .border(.gray)
            Spacer()
            Text("Incoming value: \(incomingTextFieldvalue)")
            Text("This value: \(textFieldValue)")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that when passing a `destination` for the `NavigationLink` you don't need to use `{}`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! This also works, but in my case I want the first view to keep its value.

Comment: Hello, I'm glad I could help you! Well in this case I think @Asperi's answer is better suited to be the accepted one. It would be great if you accept his answer, Have a great day!

Comment: Absolutely, I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need another variable to do that; just modify the @State variable itself.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var inputTextValue = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                TextField("",text: $inputTextValue)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .border(.gray)
                NavigationLink(destination: {SecondView(textFieldValue: inputTextValue)}, label: {Text("To second view")})
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var textFieldValue = "Initial Value in view 2"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextField("",text: $textFieldValue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .border(.gray)
            Spacer()
            Text("This value: \(textFieldValue)")

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```